# Angular 4 date pipe, no timezone

Tags: angular, typescript, timezone, date-pipe

I'm using date pipe to display record date to user on front-end. Back-end get's the date from DB and through rest I'm getting this from server to front-end. And there I use :

```
<div>{{myDate | date:'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss'}}</div>
```

The problem is, this time is with my own timezone witch I don't want. I need it to be the date exactly the same as I got from the server.

PS. I can't use something like that :

```
let myDataWithoutLocal = formatMyDate(myDate);
```

because date comes in multiple object's, so I would really like to modify the pipe, than the object or it's data.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I just saw that my question missed a solution. So there it is :

The date was fine when I was running app on my workstation, but magic happened when it was running on our company's server. **Solution : the server had wrong timezone selected.**

Thank's!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

```
<!--output '2015-06-15 09:03 AM GMT+9'-->
<p>The custom date with fixed timezone is {{myDate  | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a z':'+0900'}}</p>
```

Refer:- https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: This only works if you don't have to deal with Daylight Savings Time, which many zones should have.