# How to format Date with pipe in Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to display a particular date in a certain format. E.g '24 September 2019'. How would I go about doing that using pipes in Angular?

Angular version 7

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 4 date pipe, no timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48641481/angular-4-date-pipe-no-timezone)

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35754586/format-date-as-dd-mm-yyyy-using-pipes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format date as dd/MM/yyyy using pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35754586/format-date-as-dd-mm-yyyy-using-pipes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be something like this, you could refer the documentation **[here](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)**

```
<div>{{ today | date : 'd MMMM yyyy' }} </div>
```